# Can we create a component with parameterized constructor?

Tags: atg-dynamo

In ATG, in order to create a component we first create a java class with default constructor along with its configuration file.
What if I want to have a parameterized constructor for my class.
Can I create a component now with this?
If yes, explain how this can be done and how to pass those parameters.
If no, give the reason for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can create parameterized constructor in ATG and you can achive this as follows.

```
package mycompany;
public class MyClass {
    private String mystring;
    private int mynumber;

    // The constructor requires two arguments.
    public MyClass (String pMyString, int pMyNumber) {
        mystring = pMyString;
        mynumber = pMyNumber;
    }

    public String getmMyString() {
        return mystring;
    }
    public int getmMyNumber() {
        return mynumber;
    }
}
```

and components for this.

```
$class=mycompany.MyClass
$instanceFactory=/atg/dynamo/nucleus/ParameterConstructorInstanceFactory
$constructor.param[0].value=Hello
$constructor.param[0].type=String
$constructor.param[1].value=321
$constructor.param[1].type=int
```

for details please follow atg doc.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36434_01/Platform.10-1-2/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s0208parameterconstructorinstancefact01.html